# How to update Database fields in crystal reports referring to Ref cursor

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, oracle10g

I have crystal reports which executes the stored procedure and it returns data as ref cursor. For ex: Existing report returns 2 columns i have modified the procedure to include another column in the returning cursor, However the additional column is not reflected in the crystal reports. I need this column to be included in the report. How can i do this?

Comment: try using `Verify database` option

Comment: @Siva Can you explain how to user Verify database?

Comment: Database --> Verify. Works awesome!!! thanks